# All letters are capitalized in Qt android ONe plus device

Tags: android, qt, qml

In Qt android app ,all letters are forced to capitalize in one plus mobile device.

[image]

The code part is

```
         Text {
                id: emailInput
                height: 40
                text: ""
                anchors.top: parent.top
                passwordshowActivityVisible: false
                headerBackgroundVisible: true
                placeholdertext: "Email Address"
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: 20
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
}
```

Comment: Try to explicitly set [font.capitalization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#font.capitalization-prop)

Comment: I have tried font capitalization , but did not work. Not only in text box all test are capitalized like "FORGOT PASSWORD"

Comment: Seems really weird... Can you find the source for Text.qml in your Qt installation folder? Maybe you can find some hint there, not sure how to otherwise help

Comment: It's not just you, I have the same issue. OnePlus 5T, Qt 5.13.1, Android 9.